# Why isn't $timeout working when I pass a predefined function as the first argument?

Tags: angularjs

The following executes immediately and ignores the timeout entirely

```
var print = function(){
console.log('hey');
}
$timeout(print(), 2200);
```

But this works perfectly fine

```
$timeout(function(){console.log('hey')}, 2200);
```

Why can't I use a variable that contains the function?

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to the `$timeout` constructor is a function, not an invocation of a function.

Change it to `$timeout(print, 2200);` and that should work fine :)

You can read more about the `$timeout` service here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Hope that helps!

Comment: Upvoted, it is the only answer which **explain** the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect:

```
var print = function(){
console.log('hey');
}
$timeout(print(), 2200);
```

The correct form to pass the function is:

```
var print = function(){
console.log('hey');
}
$timeout(function(){
    print()
}, 2200);
```

Because $timeout need a function in first argument.

Can you Read this in [Angular Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Answer (score 1):

Use only `print`

```
var print = function(){
    console.log('hey');
}
$timeout(print, 2200);
```

Here is working example with jQuery function `setTimeout()`

```js
var print = function(){
  console.log('hey');
}
setTimeout(print, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var print = function(){
console.log('hey');
}
$timeout(print, 2200);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$timeout(print, 2200);`

Remove the paranthesis from the function

Answer (score 0):

There are already a few answers that show how to fix it, but to answer your question:

> Why can't I use a variable that contains the function?

The thing is, you can, but that's just not what you're doing. When you create a function like this:

```
var print = function(){
    console.log('hey');
}
```

You end up with a variable named `print` that points to a function. You can now do two things with it

1. pass it along as a function
2. invoke it and get it's **result**

While it's not immediately apparent, every function in JavaScript always returns a result. Your function is equivalent to this:

```
var print = function(){
    console.log('hey');
    return undefined;
}
```

So when you're using a timeout you need a *function* as the first parameter. Since invoking your `print()` function yields a result (of `undefined`), this is not what the timeout function requires.

So to recap:

**Correct**

```
$timeout(print, 2200); // Pass the function as an argument
```

**Incorrect**

```
$timeout(print(), 2200); // Pass the value undefined as an argument
```